# Problemas con la herencia de clases java

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy creando una lista de Entradas de distintos tipos para un negocio (subclases).
Mi clase general es `Entradas`, que extiende a `PaseTarde`, `PaseLaborable` y `PaseGeneral`. Este último extiende a su vez a `TempBaja`, `TempAlta` y `TempMedia` para las distintas temporadas.

El pase general y por extensión sus hijos, pueden tener el atributo de `boolean PaseVIP`, pero no los otros dos tipos.

Por último tengo la `class PanelEntradas`, donde visualizo y controlo la emisión de entradas.

Así, en el panel tengo un `ArrayList<Entrada>` para acumularlas todas y poder sacar una lista de información que luego visualizare mediante una JTable.

El problema que encuentro, es que cuando recorro el ArrayList y utilizo el método getVIP() que está declarado en PaseGeneral me da un error de tipo, a pesar de que utilizo un statment `if`(entrada.getClass() = "PaseGeneral") para controlar si estoy actuando sobre la clase (y subclasses) que contienen dicho método.

Estoy seguro que de que tiene que ver con la instancias y sus clases, pero consigo ver donde está el problema. Solamente debería afectarme en caso de que la clase de mi instancia sea igual a la que tiene declarado dicho método,?no?

Muestro el código.

Clase madre Entrada

```
public class Entrada
{
    int idEntrada;
    String tipoEntrada;
}
```

Subclase abstracta de Pase General (Acepta VIP)

```
public abstract class PaseGral extends Entrada
{
    boolean VIP;

    public PaseGral()
    {
        this.tipoEntrada = "PASE_GRAL";
        this.precio = 60;
    }

    public void setVIP(boolean VIP)
    {
        this.VIP = VIP;
    }

    public boolean getVIP()
    {
        return this.VIP;
    } 
}
```

Ejemplo de clase sin opción a VIP

```
public class PaseLaborable extends Entrada
{ 
    public PaseLaborable()
    {
        this.tipoEntrada = "PASE LABORABLE";
        this.precio = 60;
        this.parking = false;

    }
}
```

Ejemplo de subclase con opción a VIP

```
public class Media extends PaseGral
{
    Temp temporada;

    public Media(boolean parking, boolean VIP)
    {
        this.temporada = Temp.MEDIA;
        this.tipoEntrada = "PASE_GRAL";
        super.VIP = VIP;
        super.parking = parking;
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase que agrupa todo, donde tengo el problema.

```
public class PanelEntradas
{
    Temporada temporada;
    private ArrayList<Entrada> entradas;

    public PanelEntradas(JTabbedPane marcoPanel)
    {
        entradas = new ArrayList<Entrada>();
        JButton btnListar = new JButton("Lista de Entradas");
        btnListar.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {  
                listarEntradas(entradas);  
            }  
        }
        );

    }

    private void listarEntradas(ArrayList<Entrada> entradas)
    {
        if(entradas.size() > 0) {

            JFrame listaEntradas = new JFrame("Lista de Entradas");
            String columnas[]={"ID", "Tipo", "Fecha", "VIP", "Parking"}; 
            DefaultTableModel entradasTM = new DefaultTableModel(columnas, 0);
            JTable tablaEntradas = new JTable(entradasTM);

            for(Entrada entrada : entradas)
            {
                int idEntrada = entrada.getIdEntrada();
                String tipoEntrada = entrada.getTipo();
                Date fecha = entrada.getFecha();
                System.out.println("clase" + entrada.getClass());


//------ LINEA ERROR --------------------
                boolean VIP = entrada.getClass().equals("PaseGral") ? entrada.getVIP(): false;
//--------------------------------------
                boolean parking = entrada.getParking();

                Object[] datos = {idEntrada, tipoEntrada, fecha, VIP, parking};
                entradasTM.addRow(datos);
            }

            // Botón cerrar

            // Layout de la tabla

        } else {
            // Aviso de lista vacía
        }
    }
}
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
PanelEntradas.java:155 error: cannot find symbol 
boolean VIP = entrada.getClass().equals("PaseGral") ? entrada.getVIP() : false;
                                                             ^    
symbol: methos getVIP()
location: variable entrada of type Entrada
```

GRACIAS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿La clase `Entrada` tiene método `getVIP`? No. Entonces no puedes hacer esto, ya está.

A ti te parece que si has hecho una comprobación con if por el nombre de clase el compilador también lo tiene que saber pero no, el compilador no sabe que el objeto `entrada` es de tipo *PaseGral* y, de hecho, el objeto `entrada` es de tipo *Entrada*.

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
boolean VIP = false;
if (entrada insatnceof PaseGral) {
    VIP = ((PaseGral) entrada).getVIP();
}
```

Pero esto no es buen diseño. Si tienes que usar *instanceof* entonces hay algo que no está bien.